# prevent sudo log_output from storing stdout

Tags: sudo, logs

I am trying to log what users are doing wuth sudo. On the same time I do not want to record their passwords in normal situations. So using log_output seems like a good way and it basically does most of what I want, there is just one issue.

If I run a command like this:

`sudo mysqldump db_name | gzip > db_name.sql.gz`

I end up with tons of data in my log files, since all of the commands stdout is captured by log_output in the stdout file.

Basically I never need the stdout output, because I'm only interested in what the user did and that's usually either in the log file itself, or in ttyout. For single-line commands like above, there's even enough information in auth.log

Do you know of any way to prevent sudo writing the stdout file? Or maybe it would be enough to somehow limit the logging to things like

```
sudo su -
sudo /bin/bash
sudo -s
sudo -i
...
```

basically anything where the user gets a shell.

This is not meant to be 100% secure and tamper-proof. It's more meant as a tool, where we can check what a user did who is maybe on holiday, or can't remember what happened, etc.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you'd want anything special. By default `sudo` logs the command. For example on my Debian systems, `sudo id` logs `May 13 20:50:26 pi sudo:  roaima : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/roaima ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/id` in `/var/log/auth.log`. If you `sudo -s`, though, you won't get any of the detail of what went on ithe shell session, just that the user got a shell.

Comment: exactly, this exists and is good enough for sudo-oneliners. But I want to know what the user does during e.g. sudo -s, which can be achieved with log_output, which records the whole sudo session. Unfortunately it also captures stdout on one-liners like above, which I don't need / want / can have.

Comment: What about `sudo vipw` ... `:sh`? You're not going to be able to capture everything unless you capture everything.